# Problem whith parsing EpicGames Store on Python

Tags: python, parsing, request, lxml, urllib3

I have a problem parsing the EpicGames Store in python. I would like to receive information about free games. I am writing code, but I only get []. I tested it on other sites and everything was fine. I have Python 3.8.8

```
from lxml.html import fromstring
import urllib.request

response = urllib.request.urlopen('https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/').read()
page = fromstring(response)
games = page.xpath('/html/body/div[1]/div/div[4]/main/div/div[3]/div/div/span[4]/div/div/section/div/div[1]/div/div/a/div/div/div[3]/span[1]')
print(games)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you want to try the following code:

```py
import requests
from pprint import pprint

import lxml.html


if __name__ == '__main__':
    base_url = 'https://www.epicgames.com'

    response = requests.get(base_url + '/store/pl/free-games')
    root = lxml.html.fromstring(response.content)

    results = root.xpath(".//a[contains(@class, 'DiscoverCardLayout__link')]")

    for result in results:
        url = base_url + result.get('href', '')
        title_item = result.xpath(
            ".//span[@data-testid='offer-title-info-title']")
        studio_item = results[0].xpath(
            ".//span[@data-testid='offer-title-info-subtitle']")
        is_free_item = results[0].xpath(
            ".//div[@data-component='PriceLayout']")

        try:

            pprint(
                {
                    'url': url,
                    'title': title_item[0].text,
                    'studio': studio_item[0].text_content(),
                    'is_free': (
                        is_free_item[0].text_content().strip() == 'Bezpłatne')
                }
            )

        except IndexError:
            continue
```

Save it in a file, like 'epic_script.py' and run it: `python3 epic_script.py`.

For today, 2021-07-13, print results as bellow:

```
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Fortnite',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/fortnite'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Rocket League®',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/rocket-league'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Warface',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/warface'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Genshin Impact',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/genshin-impact'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Phantasy Star Online 2 New Genesis',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/phantasy-star-online-2'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Scavengers',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/scavengers'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Core',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/core'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Rogue Company',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/rogue-company'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Magic The Gathering Arena',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/mtg-arena'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Idle Champions of the Forgotten Realms',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/idle-champions-of-the-forgotten-realms'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Dauntless',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/dauntless'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Paladins',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/paladins'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Trackmania',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/trackmania'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'SMITE',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/smite'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'World of Warships',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/world-of-warships'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Spellbreak',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/spellbreak'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Heroes & Generals WWII',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/heroes-and-generals-wwii'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'CRSED: F.O.A.D.',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/crsed-f-o-a-d'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Auto Chess',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/auto-chess'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Path of Exile',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/path-of-exile'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Magic: Legends',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/magic-legends'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Diabotical',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/diabotical'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Neverwinter',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/neverwinter'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Star Trek Online',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/star-trek-online'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Primordials: Battle of Gods',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/primordials-battle-of-gods'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Might & Magic: Chess Royale',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/might-and-magic-chess-royale'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Hyper Scape™',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/hyper-scape'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Battle Breakers',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/battle-breakers'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'SpellForce 3: Versus Edition',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/spellforce-3-versus'}
{'is_free': True,
 'studio': 'Epic Games',
 'title': 'Delores: A Thimbleweed Park mini-adventure',
 'url': 'https://www.epicgames.com/store/pl/p/thimbleweed-park--delores'}
```